# IIB - Creating an integration server on the integration node never completes

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

Using IBM Integration Bus V10.0.0.3 on Windows. I encountered an issue in the Integration Toolkit that I can reproduce on a command line. I can create a new local integration node but when I try to create a new integration server on that node, the command never completes successfully.

As an administrator, to create the node I do:

```
mqsiprofile
mqsicreatebroker NEWNODE
mqsistart NEWNODE
```

All these commands are successful. Then I try to create the integration server with:

```
mqsicreateexecutiongroup NEWNODE -e SoapIS -w 500 -v D:\log.txt
```

The log.txt shows the following:

```
DUMBLEDORE
serializer.version=1.0
commsmessage.type=com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.Request
commsmessage.sessionId=3c38dc7a08a742e6a8a95f7afd2eed8b
...
commsmessage.operationtype=reregister
commsmessage.configobjecttype=<all>

2016-06-15 13:58:39.0371 com.ibm.broker.             { com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.LocalCMPSender.send()
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0371 com.ibm.broker.             } com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.LocalCMPSender.send()
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0371 com.ibm.broker.           } com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.SendManager.send()
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0371 com.ibm.broker.         } com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.AdministeredObjectPool.sendHeartbeatResponse()
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0371 com.ibm.broker.         { com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.AdministeredObjectPool.getLogEntriesFromStringTokenizer()
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0371 com.ibm.broker.         } com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.AdministeredObjectPool.getLogEntriesFromStringTokenizer() retVal=[]
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0371 com.ibm.broker.         { com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.AdministeredObjectPool.findObjectFromResponseElement()
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0371 com.ibm.broker.           d[3]: affectedConfigObjectType=<unknown>,affectedUUID=null,affectedObjectsParentUUID=null
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0371 com.ibm.broker.           d[3]: referenceParentUUID=null,referenceParentType=null
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0371 com.ibm.broker.         } com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.AdministeredObjectPool.findObjectFromResponseElement() retVal=null
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0371 com.ibm.broker.         d[3]: The actionresponse does not refer to an instantiable object.
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0371 com.ibm.broker.       } com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.AdministeredObjectPool.processResponse()
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0371 com.ibm.broker.     } com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.ReceiveManager.action()
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0371 com.ibm.broker.   } com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.LocalCMPReceiver.deliverMessage()
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0825 main...........   d[2]: AdministeredObjectPool deregistered a thread that is no longer waiting for a 'actionresponse': main
2016-06-15 13:58:39.0825 main...........   d[2]: AdministeredObjectPool registered a waiting for 'actionresponse' thread: main
```

The last 2 lines repeat many times.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue on Windows 64-bit,

Fixed by applying the IBM Integration Bus 10 fix pack 5 released on Fix Central 2016-05-27. I was able to create the integration server and deply a bar file no problem.

Please note that I also tested the Fix Pack 5 on Linux X86_64, and the issue does not seem to be resolved on Redhat RHEL 7.2 64-it.

Hope this helps someone else.